# How to do I get the output of a shell script executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I am using below code in my jenkinspipeline:

```
inv_id = sh(script: "project/abc.sh ${params.p_name} ${params.env} ${params.cver}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

This fails and the stage execution exits.

```
/var/jenkins/workspace/tion@tmp/durable-911397b7/script.sh: line 1: ${params.p_name}: bad substitution
```

```
Parameters block:

parameters {
string(name: 'p_name', description: 'Please start the project name', defaultValue: 'abc')
string(name: 'env', defaultValue: 'dev')
string(name: 'cver', defaultValue: '7.0.1.0')
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your `parameters` block?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Added the param block

Comment: Problem here could be that your string assigned to `p_name` has spaces in it, and it is being passed to your shell script through a shell interpreter that may not interpret that correctly. Consider converting that `abc.sh` to Groovy.

Comment: Job params can be access from environment variable in bash, thus try `script: 'project/abc.sh ${p_name} ${env} ${cver}'`

Comment: @yong, yes atleast the script execuites this time, but does not store value in ```                          inv_id = sh(script: "project/abc.sh ${p_name} ${env} ${cver}", returnStdout: true).trim()```

```. My abc script is a shell script which returns inventory_id

Comment: you should print out the `inventory_id` in `abc.sh`, like using `echo $inventory_id`.  `returnStdout: true` will capture all message output to terminal console, If there are other message , you need to extract `inventory_id`, thus the simple way is to output `inventory_id` to a file in `abc.sh`, then get `inventory_id` by reading the file.   `sh(script: 'project/abc.sh ${p_name} ${env} ${cver}')`  `inv_id = sh(script: 'cat inventory_id.txt', returnStdout: true).trim()`